# My whole is an executive title

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My prefix is alternative for a net,
>   My infix is an important assignment.
>   My suffix is a place you don’t want to go,
>   My whole is an executive you may know.

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My prefix is alternative for a net,

> com - short for intercom, or an alternative internet top-level domain to .net

My infix is an important assignment.

> mission

My suffix is a place you don’t want to go,

> ER - don't want to have to go to an emergency room

My whole is an executive you may know.

> commissioner - an official in charge, e.g. the baseball commissioner

Comment: Correct! That's the answer. Great job!